# Prevent keyboard dismiss on button click

Tags: android

I am working on a chat application. In that i need the keyboard to remain visible even after the user clicks the send button like in Whatsapp.

Comment: Can you provide some code that you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one it will always show the keyboard in an specific activity, just state **android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible"** in your Android Manifest.

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
 android:label="@string/app_name"
 android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible" />
```

Comment: For activity yes this will work. Sorry i should have been more specific. Here my chat is a fragment.